# Reference for moduli stack of principal G-bundles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, reference-request

Hi,

I'm looking for a reference for the fact that the moduli stack $M_{GL_r,X}$ of $GL_r$-bundles over $X$ is an algebraic (Artin) stack. I'm only interested in the case where $X$ is a curve (for now).

I think this is supposed to be in Laumon-Moret--Bailly's "Champs Algebriques", but my French is not so great and I have been unable to find it in there. If it is actually in there, can you help a non-Francophone out?

Thanks!

Comment: See theorem 4.6.2.1 on page 29 of above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually don't think$^{\dagger}$ that this example is in Laumon/Moret-Bailey, but Jonathan Wang's senior thesis is a detailed write up in the style of LMB (and in English!) of this fact: [thesis](http://jonathanpwang.com/writings/thesis.pdf) and the arXiv [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4828).

$^{\dagger}$ Edit: I stand corrected!

Answer (score 3):

This is in LM-B.  It is Théorème 4.6.2.1 on p. 29.  A generalization is proved in Max Lieblich's article.

MR2233719 (2008c:14022)
Lieblich, Max(1-PRIN)
Remarks on the stack of coherent algebras.
Int. Math. Res. Not. 2006, Art. ID 75273, 12 pp.
14D20 (14A20)

Wang's senior thesis is also a well-written source.

**Edit:** The reference for Laumon and Moret-Bailly was already posted by Donu.  Sorry for missing that.

Comment: I see that Donu already posted the reference!  The generalization in Lieblich's article is Theorem 2.1.1 (in English).

Comment: No problem. Also, I think Behrend's thesis (from his webpage) does
some of this.